# How do I keep adding the values of my input fields into another tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get the values from the two input boxes below the "Welcome to Discussion Portal" i.e. input boxes with the ids "textarea_text" and "id2"
and put these values on the left side two made tags i.e. h2 tag and p tag with the ids "addh2_in_col1" and "addp_in_col1"
The values are getting added but,
the problem is that they keep getting updated every time i click the submit button.
I want all the the values keep getting added to there
Here is my code:

````
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <style>
    #h1a{
  background: rgb(2,0,36);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(9,121,120,1) 37%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);
  color: white;
}
button{
  background-color: #0099ff;
  height: 48px;
  width: 200px;
}
#id1{
  height: 45px;
  width: 200px;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
textarea{
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
}
  </style>
  <script>
  function function2(){
  var a = document.getElementById('id2').value;
  document.getElementById("addh2_in_col1").innerHTML = a;
  var b = document.getElementById('textarea_text').value;
  document.getElementById('addp_in_col1').innerHTML = b;
}
  </script>
<div class="row">
<h1 id="h1a">Discussion Portal</h1>
<div  class="column">
<button>New Question Form</button> <input id="id1" type="text" placeholder="search questions..." ><br>
<div class="div-2">
  <h2 id='addh2_in_col1'></h2>
  <p id='addp_in_col1'></p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="column">
<h1>Welcome to Discussion Portal</h1>
<p>Enter a subject and question to get started</p><br>
<input id="id2" type="text" placeholder="subject" ><br><br><br>
<textarea id="textarea_text" placeholder="Question"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="function2()">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: call the  `function2()` on input - "input" event ....

Comment: What do you mean by "I want all the the values keep getting added". Do you want a new title and question to appear each time you click submit so you have a list?

Comment: Yes Sir Alex, as you run this and add values to the the two input box under "Welcome to discussion portal", it gets added on the left side of it 
i want the same thing happening again but under it as the values i have added before should remain and new values should get added

Comment: `.innerHTML += a;` and `.innerHTML += b;` would do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You replaced your variable each time you clicked. I made it with array and plus

```js
function function2(){
let a = []
let b = []
  a.push(document.getElementById('id2').value);
  a.forEach((item) => {
  const para = document.createElement("h2");
  para.innerHTML += item;
document.getElementById("div-2").appendChild(para);

  })
  b.push(document.getElementById('textarea_text').value);
  b.forEach((item) => {
  const para = document.createElement("p");
  para.innerHTML += item;
  document.getElementById("div-2").appendChild(para);
  })
}
```

```css
#h1a{
  background: rgb(2,0,36);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(9,121,120,1) 37%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);
  color: white;
}
button{
  background-color: #0099ff;
  height: 48px;
  width: 200px;
}
#id1{
  height: 45px;
  width: 200px;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
textarea{
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<h1 id="h1a">Discussion Portal</h1>
<div  class="column">
<button>New Question Form</button> <input id="id1" type="text" placeholder="search questions..." ><br>
<div class="div-2" id="div-2">
  <h2 id='addh2_in_col1'></h2>
  <p id='addp_in_col1'></p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="column">
<h1>Welcome to Discussion Portal</h1>
<p>Enter a subject and question to get started</p><br>
<input id="id2" type="text" placeholder="subject" ><br><br><br>
<textarea id="textarea_text" placeholder="Question"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="function2()">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sir, you have done the job, but the problem is that it should be displayed below the first inputs and in the same manner